# Howto use a VAO with position, texcoord and normal

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have got a Wavefront OBJ Parser up running but after spending endless hours trying to figure out how i load the data in OpenGL i finally had to give up.

This is how the code is built:

```
struct ObjMeshVertex{
    Vector3f pos;
    Vector2f texcoord;
    Vector3f normal;
};

struct ObjMeshFace{
    ObjMeshVertex vertices[3];
};

struct ObjMesh{
    std::vector<ObjMeshFace> faces;
};

ObjMesh myMesh;

for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i){
    ObjMeshFace face;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        face.vertices[j].pos        = positions[faces[i].pos_index[j] - 1];
        face.vertices[j].texcoord   = texcoords[faces[i].tex_index[j] - 1];
        face.vertices[j].normal     = normals[faces[i].nor_index[j] - 1];
    }
    myMesh.faces.push_back(face);
}
```

Normally when i create a simple cube, the array looks something like this: `{posX, posY, posZ, normX, normY, normZ}`.

And by using the offset with `glVertexAttribPointer` its pretty simple to load the data.

But i have no clue how this is done?

EDIT 
Setup:

```
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_boxVAO);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_boxVAO);

    int sizeOfFaces = myMesh.faces.size() * sizeof(ObjMeshFace);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_boxBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _boxBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfFaces, &(myMesh.faces[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)offsetof(ObjMeshVertex, texcoord));        
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)offsetof(ObjMeshVertex, normal));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Draw:

```
glBindVertexArrayOES(_boxVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indicesize);
```

Where indicesize = myMesh.faces.size()

Comment: It's hard to understand what is the problem for you. Is it the position faces, texture faces and face/vertex normals in the .obj file which need to be "merged" somehow ? Is it the handling of interleaved VAOs or something else ?

Comment: @ViktorLatypov, im sorry that it seems unclear. But my problem is how to load my `myMesh` into a VAO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just asking how to send the data to glBufferData, then you just get the pointer to the first face in myMesh, and call glBufferData on that (assuming that everything is tightly packed).

```
int sizeOfFaces = myMesh.faces.size() * sizeof(ObjMeshFace);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfFaces, &(myMesh.faces[0]), usage);
```

Then you can just set up the pointers to this interleaved structure:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), 0);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)(sizeof(Vector3f)));
glNormalPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)(sizeof(Vector3f) + sizeof(Vector2f)));
```

One thing you might need to check is that your structs aren't being padded (I'm less sure about how to enable/disable this).

Just double check and assert that:

```
sizeof(ObjMeshVertex) == 2 * sizeOf(Vector3f) + sizeOf(Vector2f);
sizeof(ObjMeshFace) == 3 * sizeOf(ObjMeshVertex);
```

If this isn't true you might need to make some adjustments for struct padding.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. But the two last pointers are causing problems with the last attribute in the function (sizeof). Seems like it needs a pointer for that.

Comment: the first casting works, the secondary complains about the sum-symbol

Comment: It shouldn't complain if you make sure the void cast wraps both values: (void*)(a+b) and not (void*)(a)+b. Either that or my C is too rusty. Also I realized you're using glVertexAttribPointer, you can change my glVertex|TexCoord|Normal to VertexAttrib with no problem.

Comment: Alternatively you could do it like they do in this example, it should apply to your situation: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples

Comment: `glNormalPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)(sizeof(Vector3f) + sizeof(Vector2f))));` still fails though..

Comment: Sorry I must be wrong then, not sure how to add them. For now you can just hardcode the byte offset as (void*)20

Comment: One variable too many. I changed it to `glNormalPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, (void*)(sizeof(Vector3f) + sizeof(Vector2f)));
`

Comment: Oh, you're right, but your new line is wrong. Should be glNormalPointer (GL_FLOAT, sizeOf(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)(sizeOf(...)));

Comment: Is it possible to use VAO around VBO? Also how do i draw this? `glDrawArrays`??

Comment: I tried to look through http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html but alot of code is missing, so its confusing to figure out whats happening completely. They have an example based on VAO

Comment: My question has just been updated. I get no error, but totally "black screen", so something is not right i assume.

Comment: My last code update is actually showing something similar to my model. But the graphic is flickering. There must still me some issue.

Comment: @JavaCake You probably now have a completely different problem from your current question, which in turn has been answered correctly by Tim.

Comment: To avoid thinking about any padding issues, you can just use the good old `(void*)offsetof(ObjMeshVertex, normal)` instead of some manual `sizeof` mess.

Comment: @ChristianRau, i have updated my code, although `(void*)offsetof(ObjMeshVertex, position)` was not possible. I still only get the base of my 3D model, which is quite odd.

Comment: @JavaCake If this code is your real code, then of course you have an error in the third `glVertexAttribPointer` call, the second argument should be 3 instead of 2, otherwise your normals all have a z of 0.

Comment: @ChristianRau, fixed that typo, but it did not fix the problem.